# Connection time out exception while sending mail through Java Mail API

Tags: java, email, tomcat, jakarta-mail

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTPHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
        Authenticator Auth= new MailAuthenticator();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, Auth);
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //
        //
        Transport.send(msg);
```

The mail is sending successfully most of times but some times it is not sending and tomcat shows

```
        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: "SMTPHost - IP "     , port: 587;
```

nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

This message appear every few hours in Tomcat logs.

javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
    This message also appears rarely in a day.
```

any help really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should ask for help your ISP support service

Comment: maybe try to figure out why your mailserver is rejecting connections... Check logs...

Comment: I have contacted them. They said, from their end it seem fine. The response time to send an email always take more time (after click button it takes 1 minutes or more to send email and redirect to success page, sometimes no email sending at all), so I'm not sure whether it could be issue on my Java code or firewall blocking something or anything else..:(

Comment: A connection timing out is exactly what it says it is. It is rarely a pure java code error. If you are constantly using the same server and it goes wrong occasionally, it is more likely to be network glitches, a server refusing a connection because it is busy or even a load balanced service forwarding a request to a server not being able to answer.

Comment: It was worked well. After switching to new SMTP Host, we facing this issue from last few weeks, Automated Java mails (just text message) takes long time (more than a minutes, page simply loading) to send & redirect to success response page and sometimes Connection timed out/reset errors in tomcat logs. If it is Java code error, what are the things I can check it out in my code? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 methods Transport.send() and Transport.sendMessage() available in the java mail API.
You can read [Difference between Transport methods send and sendMessage](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#send)

Try creating your own transport object and use sendMessage() for sending multiple messages.

Using Transport.send() might be the reason why automated java mails are taking more time.

If above is not the case, then problem is with the network.

Comment: I have used below line in my java code,
    session.setDebug(true);  I got     javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", port 587, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
me javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset after "isSSL false", it simple hang.

Comment: sometimes its going further, 220 xxxxx.xxx.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 15 Aug 2014 xxx
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", port: 587  later Email sent successfully

Comment: Do we mean to say you are still facing the problem or is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout for getting connection. May be during load times, the app is unable to get connection within specified time, and throws exception.